# Angular routing for Bootstrap content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use AngularJS mainly for seamless routing of an already functioning webpage. The idea is simple: / stands for the root (index.html), /detail stands for a detailed view (detail_zerohouse.html). However, even with the app and both controllers defined, all I can get is a weirdly layed out index.html and I can't even get to the detail view, all I get is an 404 Not Found. Here's my code:

```js
----------------- main.js ----------------------------
  
var architectApp = angular.module("architectApp");
architectApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'indexCtrl'
        }).
        when('/detail', {
            templateUrl: 'detail_zerohouse.html',
            controller: 'detailCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);

-------------- indexCtrl.js ----------------------------
  
architectApp.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope){

});


-------------- detailCtrl.js --------------------------
  
architectApp.controller('detailCtrl', function($scope){

});
```

```html
-------------------------- root.html ---------------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="architectApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>AngularJS Root</title>

    <!-- AngularJS-->
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/indexCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/detailCtrl.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Google Roboto Font-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Main user stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
        <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
        <!-- Media helper Fancybox-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
        <!-- Thumbs helper Fancybox-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- SmoothScroll JS-->
    <script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
//                initialize SmoothScroll
            smoothScroll.init();
//                set Fancybox properties
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
//                fitToView       : false, opens the image already in fullscreen
                prevEffect      : 'none',
                nextEffect      : 'none',
                closeBtn        : false,
                closeClick      : true,
                hideOnOverlayClick : true,
                helpers     : {
                    title   : { type : 'inside' },
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body class="container-fluid" ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
------------------------ index.html ------------------------

 <nav class="nav  navbar-default" id="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Peter Danko</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">architektúra <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#navigation">interiér</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#navigation">o mne</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav> <!-- end nav -->

    <!--<div id="mainWrap" class="container-fluid">-->

        <div class="row tileRow" id="firstRow" style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <a href="detail.html">
                <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                        <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                    <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                    <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                    <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row end -->

        <div class="row tileRow">
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 tile">
                <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row end -->



-----------------------  detail.html  ------------------------------


 <nav class="nav  navbar-default navbar-top-offset" id="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Peter Danko</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">architektúra <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#navigation">budova</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">interiér</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">o mne</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav> <!-- end nav -->



    <!--<div id="mainWrap" class="container-fluid">-->

        <div class="row tileRow" id="firstRow" style="margin-top: 5px;">

            <a href="index.html#navigation">
                <div class="col-md-2 tile logoTile">
                        <img src="img/dummy.png" class="img-responsive" id="">
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="col-md-6 doubleTile">
                <a href="img/zerohouse/7.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancy"><img src="img/zerohouse/7thumb.png" class="img-responsive" id=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 tile">
                <a href="img/zerohouse/8text.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancy"><img src="img/zerohouse/8text.png" class="img-responsive" id=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 tile">
                <a href="img/zerohouse/8plan.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancy"><img src="img/zerohouse/8plan.png" class="img-responsive" id=""></a>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- row end -->

        <div class="row tileRow">

            <div class="col-md-2 tile">
                <a href="img/zerohouse/11.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancy"><img src="img/zerohouse/11thumb.png" class="img-responsive" id=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 tile">
                <a href="img/zerohouse/12.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancy" title="Plan"><img src="img/zerohouse/12thumb.png" class="img-responsive" id=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 tile">
                <a href="img/zerohouse/10.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancy"><img src="img/zerohouse/10thumb.png" class="img-responsive" id=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 doubleTile">
                <a href="img/zerohouse/9.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancy"><img src="img/zerohouse/9thumb.png" class="img-responsive" id=""></a>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- row end -->
```

Thanks for any help, I've tried everything I could think of but got nowhere.

```
/
-/css
-/fancybox
-/helpers
-/img
-/js
  -detailCtrl.js
  -indexCtrl.js
  -main.js
-detail_zerohouse.html
-index.html
-root.html
```

All .html files are directly in the root folder

Comment: Please provide your working directory and folder and files structure. The 404 on routes and templateUrl is because the browser can not find the specific html file and probably you are not referencing the path correctly.

Comment: It would be more clear to insert a picture of the directory in the question.

Comment: already updated the post with the file structure

Comment: You may want to move your jquery reference to the top of angular references.

Comment: moving jQuery to the top did not help

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot the ngRoute dependency:

```
var architectApp = angular.module("architectApp",['ngRoute']);
```

Also to go to detail you should use

```
<a href="#/detail">
```

instead of

```
<a href="detail.html">
```

Also what you need to rename your file: root.html should be renamed index.html and index.html to root.html.
You need to have the index.html as your landing main page.

Comment: tried with and without the dependency, makes no difference.. it doesn't even correct the URL when typing random letters like /abcdefg..

Comment: I was manually typing the URL, in the future I will update the links with ngClick so there is no problem here

Comment: ok, but in this case you don't have any detail.html file so you receive 404, I don't understand the point...

Comment: I can't get the views loaded that's the problem.. Index.html and detail_zerohouse.html should be the files that are needed if I'm not mistaken

Comment: When typing /detail into the browser it should redirect to detail_zerohouse.html which is available as a html file

Comment: and with #/detail in the browser?

Comment: also please remove ng-view from body and insert 
     <ng-view></ng-view>

Comment: Also what you need to rename your file.
root.html should be rename index.html
and index.html to root.html
you need to have the index.html as your landing main page.

Comment: renamed the files, no difference

Answer (score 0):

got it working, the links now work like '/#/detail'. Can somebody help where to link the fancybox.js? It does not work now. Missing [ ] braces